# Convert YUY2 (YUYV) to png from the command line

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I'm using `v4l2-ctl(1)` to capture an image from my webcam and I'm trying to `convert(1)` the raw format into a png.

Here are the commands I ran.

```
# This is the format my camera outputs.
$ v4l2-ctl --device /dev/video0 --list-formats-ext
ioctl: VIDIOC_ENUM_FMT
        Type: Video Capture

        [1]: 'YUYV' (YUYV 4:2:2)
                Size: Discrete 640x480
                        Interval: Discrete 0.033s (30.000 fps)

# This is how I'm capturing an image.
$ v4l2-ctl --device /dev/video0 --set-fmt-video=width=640,height=480,pixelformat=YUYV
$ v4l2-ctl --device /dev/video0 --stream-mmap --stream-to=frame.raw --stream-count=1

# This is how I tried to convert. (This didn't work.)
$ convert -size 640x480 -depth 8 -sampling-factor 4:2:2 -colorspace YUV yuv:frame.raw frame.png
```

This gives me a green and pink png.

I also tried to display the raw image with this command.

```
$ display -size 640x480 -depth 8 -sampling-factor 4:2:2 -colorspace yuv yuv:frame.raw
```

The image looks a little better there, but there is a blue filter over the entire image.

Here is a sample image from my webcam.
http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=36420855739943963603

Comment: Can you share the YUYV file... Dropbox? Google Drive?

Comment: Sure, thing. I've updated the post with a download URL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I *think* I have the solution, but a correctly coloured reference image would help. The simplest seems to be to use `ffmpeg` to convert raw YUYV with sampling factor 4:2:2 to a PNG as follows:

```
ffmpeg -f rawvideo -s 640x480 -pix_fmt yuyv422 -i frame.raw result.png
```

If you want to do it with **ImageMagick**, you need to use its `uyvy` pixel format, but your bytes are swapped, so you need to swap them to the order **ImageMagick** expects before feeding them in - I use `dd` and its `conv=swab` option here:

```
dd if=frame.raw conv=swab | convert -sampling-factor 4:2:2 -size 640x480 -depth 8 uyvy:- result.png
```

---

If you need to swap and reorder bytes in some other, more complicated way, you can do it with `xxd` and `awk` fairly simply:

```
xxd -c2 frame.raw  | awk '{print $1,substr($2,3,2),substr($2,1,2)}' | xxd -c2 -r - | convert -sampling-factor 4:2:2 -size 640x480 -depth 8 uyvy:- result.png
```

**Keywords**: ImageMagick, image processing, command line, sub-sampled, 4:2:2, YUYV, YUY2, YUV

Comment: Huh, wow, thank you so much for this. I'm not exactly very knowledgeable about images...but why are the bytes in the wrong order for ImageMagick in the first place? If my camera is producing YUYV output, and I tell ImageMagick that, why does it need UYVY data instead? Some sort of weird endianness issue or something?

Comment: Hmm, okay, I think I might have found my answer...ImageMagick only supports UYVY, not YUYV...and since it's raw data, it has no way to know for sure what it's looking at. I must have confused YUV or some other format with the correct one.